# Implementing Discussion Group System

Tags: php, sql

I am going through the process of adding discussion groups to my site, currently users can post on topics then other users can reply, pretty simple.

Here is how I have set up the group tables

Disc_group

```
ID(int)
Name(varchar)
Description(varchar)
Created(date)
Creator(int) = user_id
invite_rule(enum 0,1) 0 = open invite, 1 = invite must be approved

Disc Users
ID(int)
User_id(int)
Group_id(int)
datejoined(date)
accepted(enum 0,1) 1 = accepted
admin(enum 0,1) 1 = admin
```

My question is I am trying to think of the most efficient way to implement this with the current topics, posts and tags tables.

**I thought I could just add "group_id" into topics, so topics with group_id of 3 for example, only display if you are viewing the group page id=3.**

I don't want any one to write code for me, I'm wanting to know what file structure would be recommended, such as

Non grouped posts are displayed in "topics.php?id=1" topics in groups displayed in "gtopics.php?id=1" for example, hopefully my issue isn't too confusing.

Comment: You described a good solution.

Comment: thanks, i'm still very new to coding etc so I always second guess myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
invite_rule(enum 0,1) 0 = open invite, 1 = invite must be approved  
accepted(enum 0,1) 1 = accepted  
admin(enum 0,1) 1 = admin
```

We can already see the above forming into a set of permissions,  I highly recommend implementing a bit masking system that way you can store the user permissions in the database and perform a logical AND when you generate your authorization token.

```
Disc Users
ID(int)
User_id(int)
Group_id(int)
datejoined(date)
accepted(enum 0,1) 1 = accepted
admin(enum 0,1) 1 = admin
```

Is going to start hurting when it comes to normalization, I would propose the following structures to replace this:

```
DISC_GROUPS  
GroupName
GroupId (not needed if group names need to be unique)    

DISC_USER_GROUPS  
UserId
GroupId

DISC_USERS
USER_ID
NAME
PERMISSIONS
DATE_JOINED
//other information about users


//This table may be unnecessary, unless you want to add some audit information perhaps
DISC_INFORMATION (THIS IS YOUR OLD DISC_USERS table)  
ID  
USERID
```

Notice how we don't duplicate information and we rely on the USER_ID relationship if we need more details.